# CSS -ms-overflow-style: none; Does NOT works anymore on Edge 115.0.1901.14

Tags: css, scrollbar, microsoft-edge

This CSS property i'm using in body element to don't show the scroll bar but keep the functionality just stop working from Edge version 115.0.1901.14. What other property can i set to get the same result?

Here my code to support Chrome, Opera, Edge, IE, Safari

```
body {
   /* hide scroll bar (keep functionality) IE, Edge, Firefox */
   -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none; /* Mozilla */
  }

  /* hide Scroll bar Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
```

Comment: Just solved with this little change:                                                                                                 
         ::-webkit-scrollbar {
            display: none;
        }

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution of the issue. You can post it as an answer and mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future with similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Just solved with this little change:

```
 ::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }
```